# SQL advanced grouping & case statements , is this possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following scenario

| System | Subsystem & Filename | File Load Start Time | File Load End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | A1 transactiontxt | 2022-06-19 08:00:00 | 2022-06-19 08:00:02 |
| Alpha | A2 userscsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:02 | 2022-06-19 08:00:05 |
| Alpha | A2 employeescsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:05 | 2022-06-19 08:00:08 |
| Alpha | A1 managerscsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:08 | 2022-06-19 08:00:16 |
| Alpha | A3 customerscsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:01 | 2022-06-19 08:00:04 |
| Gamma | A1 transactiontxt | 2022-06-19 10:00:48 | 2022-06-19 10:00:53 |
| Gamma | A2 userscsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:53 | 2022-06-19 10:00:54 |
| Gamma | A2 employeescsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:27 | 2022-06-19 10:00:30 |
| Gamma | A1 managerscsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:11 | 2022-06-19 10:00:17 |
| Gamma | A3 customerscsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:13 | 2022-06-19 10:00:14 |

I want to be able to group the summary statistics by System. The info needed is when the overall started (earliest time), when it ended (latest time), and the time it took for each subsystem to occur, in seconds. From the example above, the result should look as below:

| System | Overall System Load Start Time | Overall System Load End Time | A1 Time Taken | A2 Time Taken | A3 Time Taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 2022-06-19 08:00:00 | 2022-06-19 08:00:16 | 00:00:10 | 00:00:06 | 00:00:03 |
| Gamma | 2022-06-19 10:00:11 | 2022-06-19 10:00:54 | 00:00:11 | 00:00:04 | 00:00:01 |

I cannot find a way to do this in a query, I'm trying to do select subqueries in the select clause for each column, and at the end group by only System. But this is not possible because I'd have to use an aggregate function which is not being supported with case statements in subqueries in the select clause

My approach was something like

```
SELECT System, 
min(StartTime) as 'File Load Start Time',
max(EndTime) as 'File Load End Time', 
CASE WHEN SubSystem LIKE 'A1%' THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(s, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))) Else 0 END AS 'A1 Time Taken',
CASE WHEN SubSystem LIKE 'A2%' THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(s, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))) Else 0 END AS 'A2 Time Taken',
CASE WHEN SubSystem LIKE 'A3%' THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(s, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))) Else 0 END AS 'A3 Time Taken'
FROM TABLE GROUP BY SYSTEM
```

But this does not work because the case statements need to be in a group by clause as well, and I cannot aggregate them

Comment: Please read this : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: is what possible?

Comment: @MatBailie formatting issues that didn't let me post properly. Updated now

Comment: @ysth post updated

Comment: sure would help to know your actual column and table names.  I see no need for subqueries here, just a min and max for the overall start and end times, and conditional aggregation fo the a1/a2/a3 time taken

Comment: are the total times likely to ever be 839 hours or more?

Comment: (there's a lot more information now, but you are far from a minimal reproducible example that will get you help much faster and with less effort from others)

Comment: @ysth Sure, I added a query that I was trying to work out and got stuck, without using subqueries. And no it will not be above 839 hours

Comment: Are A1, A2, and A3 prefixes fixed and known in advance, or do you need to look at the data to determine which columns you'll need?

Comment: If you had placed your aggregation function `SUM` outside CASE , It would have worked.

Comment: your DATEDIFF syntax is not mysql; looks like SQL Server.  is your mysql tag incorrect or do you just have the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Your original query just needs a little bit of tweaking in order to work properly. I tested it in workbench. It works now.

```
SELECT System, 
    min(StartTime) as 'File Load Start Time',
    max(EndTime) as 'File Load End Time', 
    sec_to_time(sum( case when substring_index(subsystem,' ',1)='a1' then to_seconds(endtime)-to_seconds(starttime) else 0 end 
    ) )as 'A1 Time Taken',
    sec_to_time(sum( case when substring_index(subsystem,' ',1)='a2' then to_seconds(endtime)-to_seconds(starttime) else 0 end 
    ) )as 'A2 Time Taken',
    sec_to_time(sum( case when substring_index(subsystem,' ',1)='a3' then to_seconds(endtime)-to_seconds(starttime) else 0 end 
    ) )as 'A3 Time Taken'
FROM test  GROUP BY SYSTEM
;
```

Comment: I would do e.g. `case when substring_index(subsystem,' ',1)='a1' then` so you aren't including a10 etc.  also wrap a sec_to_time(...) around the time taken sum()'s

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has certainly been improved based on your suggestion.

Comment: @blabla_bingo I like your approach-- is there any alternative to sec_to_time in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your subsystems are finite and doesn't require dynamic columns (pivot/crosstab).

Folloing query should give you the desired output.

```
SELECT
    system_name AS "System", 
    min(file_load_start_time) AS "Overall System Load Start Time", 
    max(file_load_end_time) AS "Overall System Load End Time",
    (
    SELECT
        sec_to_time(sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, tsl_a1.file_load_start_time, tsl_a1.file_load_end_time)))
    FROM
        t_system_log tsl_a1
    WHERE
        tsl_a1.system_name = tsl.system_name
        AND LEFT(tsl_a1.subsystem_filename,
        2) = 'A1') AS "A1 Time Taken",
    (
    SELECT
        sec_to_time(sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, tsl_a2.file_load_start_time, tsl_a2.file_load_end_time)))
    FROM
        t_system_log tsl_a2
    WHERE
        tsl_a2.system_name = tsl.system_name
        AND LEFT(tsl_a2.subsystem_filename,
        2) = 'A2') AS "A2 Time Taken",
    (
    SELECT
        sec_to_time(sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, tsl_a3.file_load_start_time, tsl_a3.file_load_end_time)))
    FROM
        t_system_log tsl_a3
    WHERE
        tsl_a3.system_name = tsl.system_name
        AND LEFT(tsl_a3.subsystem_filename,
        2) = 'A3') AS "A3 Time Taken"
FROM
    t_system_log tsl
GROUP BY
    system_name;
```

In case, your subsystems are dynamic, you should use pivot query instead of subquery. Also subquery might impact on the performance.

[My Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f241fad47883d99f1e6f30fbfa511cfe)

EDIT:
Converting all the sub-queries to inline to improve performance.
Updated my Fiddle also.

[Updated Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ada53e16023dbe87ba72831d26077372)

```
SELECT
    system_name AS "System", 
    min(file_load_start_time) AS "Overall System Load Start Time", 
    max(file_load_end_time) AS "Overall System Load End Time",
    sec_to_time(sum(case when  LEFT(tsl.subsystem_filename, 2) = 'A1' then timestampdiff(SECOND, tsl.file_load_start_time, tsl.file_load_end_time) else 0 end)) as "A1 Time Taken",
    sec_to_time(sum(case when  LEFT(tsl.subsystem_filename, 2) = 'A2' then timestampdiff(SECOND, tsl.file_load_start_time, tsl.file_load_end_time) else 0 end)) as "A2 Time Taken",
    sec_to_time(sum(case when  LEFT(tsl.subsystem_filename, 2) = 'A3' then timestampdiff(SECOND, tsl.file_load_start_time, tsl.file_load_end_time) else 0 end)) as "A3 Time Taken"
FROM
    t_system_log tsl
GROUP BY
    system_name;
```

Comment: this is much less efficient than just using conditional aggregation would be